# How to tell column width in Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Bootstrap column width are different depending on witch device you are using and orientation.

Is there any helper that can tell me the current column width from some css selector, or just the boostrap class like "col-md-3"?

I am integrating D3.js charts within a bootstrap grid, and I need to provide D3 with the absolute size I want the chart to fit in.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to query this information from the element itself (using something like jQuery). Bootstrap columns are percentage based, so you won't know their exact width without doing the above described method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jquery `innerWidth` function to get the width of the element when you are ready to generate your chart. This should probably be after the page loads.

You'll also need to do something like this to get the width when the window size changes.

**Javascript**

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
  //if the chart takes a while to compute you may also consider a timing 
  //function to only calculate after a few hundred milliseconds of the size 
  //being the same.

  var width = $( "#mychart" ).innerWidth();
  //remove and rebuild the chart.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been answering this question a lot recently so I made this which might help explain what's going on: https://github.com/mattdell/bootstrap-grid-demo

But essentially it depends on whether you're using a container or a container-fluid. If you are using a container it then depends on your screen size. Assuming you have the default settings a col-xs-12 works out to

- x-small: between 1px and 34px depending on screen width
- small: 32.5px
- medium: 50.8333px
- large: 67.5px

In your case you're using col-md-3 so it would be

- x-small and small: between 1px and 737px depending on screen width
- medium: 455px
- large: 555px